# Article before nouns in the appositive phrase?

Tags: articles, appositives, omissibility

Here are two examples:

1. Nobody creates post-apocalyptic flicks better than George Miller, the director of the Mad Max series.

Is **the** necessary before *director*, and can it be omitted?

2. The business was doing great, and Mark Zuckerberg, CEO of Facebook, confirmed the rumors.

Can we omit an article before *CEO* or there needs to be placed **the**?

Comment: Yes, you can. "Director" and "CEO" are called 'bare-role' NPs -- bare in the sense of lacking a determiner which would be required elsewhere. They denote some kind of a role, office or position. Cf. also "They elected him president"; "Ed became managing director"; "Who wants to be secretary?"

Comment: An interesting point: If you omit the determiner, the resultant bare-role NP would no longer be an appositive modifier, but simply an ascriptive NP supplement, since the absence of a determiner would render it unable to stand alone in place of the whole NP.

Comment: The article is optional in front of *director* but it's not optional in front of *Mad Max series*. You should edit your question to insert the word in that location.

Comment: FYI, with or without the initial article "*the* director" you still need an article for "of *the* Mad Max series".

Including this one, most Questions about articles are better served over at English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

I believe that in most cases (including both your cases) either is possible, and there is no significant difference in meaning, but there is a subtle difference in connotation.

If you omit the article, you are effectively using the role as a title, rather than a description.

Looking on the iWeb corpus, ", CEO of" has 54341 instances, while ", the CEO of" has 6775; and ", president of" has 98275, against 14398 for ", the president of".

Contrast that with something that is rarely used as a title: ", inventor of" has 1668, while ", the inventor of" has 1916.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can omit that "the", since you are describing the person more accurately, in this case in the form of a title. An example:

> Queen Elizabeth the Second, by the Grace of God Queen of this Realm and of Her other Realms and Territories, Head of the Commonwealth, Defender of the Faith

(from [List of titles and honours of Elizabeth II, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_titles_and_honours_of_Elizabeth_II))

You *do* however need an article before "Mad Max series".

Answer (score -1):

The determiner 'the' is pretty much just used as a pointer.

Generally speaking, categories of things (like *CEOs*) don't require "the".  'The' is a pointer that shows you one or specific members of a group, or it "crowns" something or someone as unique.  Using 'the' works, but since they're bare-role noun phrases (i.e. a group of things)  with one form (a CEO) it isn't required.

This is also known as the 'zero article'.

> Do you like cheese?
>
> Do you like **the** cheese?

Which as I said before, is showing one member of a group.

http://www.icaltefl.com/zero-article-in-english-grammar